# How to Export a `Dataset` into a single worksheet of Excel

Tags: export, dataset, excel, excellink

I have a `Dataset`:

```
jdataSGI = {<|"country" -> "Bhutan", "subregion" -> "South Asia", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 5.|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 11.|>, <|"country" -> "Bhutan", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 3.|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 10.|>, <|"country" -> "Angola", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 5.|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 2.|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 6.|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Bangladesh", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 9.|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 6.|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 3.|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 5.|>, <|"country" -> "Cambodia", 
  "subregion" -> "South Asia", "status" -> "LDC", 
  "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 6.|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", "subregion" -> "South Asia",
   "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", "subregion" -> "South Asia",
   "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 9.|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", "subregion" -> "South Asia",
   "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 8.|>, <|"country" -> "Nepal", "subregion" -> "South Asia",
   "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 5.|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 3.|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 9.|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 4.|>, <|"country" -> "S. Islands", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 7.|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 4.|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 5.|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 8.|>, <|"country" -> "Kiribati", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "LDC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 1.|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 6.|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "GDP", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 6.|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2011., 
  "data" -> 3.|>, <|"country" -> "Vanuatu", "subregion" -> "SIDS", 
  "status" -> "ODC", "indicator" -> "EVI", "time" -> 2015., 
  "data" -> 3.|>};
```

by using @kglr's code:

```
(* Restructure "jdataSGI" to create a new dataset "ds" *)
ClearAll[reOrg, ds, indicatorList, dsgrouped];
reOrg = Query[GroupBy[{#"time", #"country"} &] /* Values /* KeyUnion, 
   Apply[Join], <|
     KeyDrop[{"indicator", "data"}]@#, #indicator -> #data|> &]; 
ds = reOrg@jdataSGI;
indicatorList = Normal[Query[First /* Keys]@ds][[5 ;;]];
dsgrouped = 
  ds[GroupBy[#country &], GroupBy[#time &], All, indicatorList];
```

I obtain:

```
yeniDS = <|"Bhutan" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 5., "EVI" -> 11.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 7., "EVI" -> 7.|>}|>, 
 "Angola" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 3., "EVI" -> 10.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 7., "EVI" -> 5.|>}|>, 
 "Bangladesh" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 2., "EVI" -> 7.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 6., "EVI" -> 9.|>}|>, 
 "Cambodia" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 6., "EVI" -> 5.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 3., "EVI" -> 6.|>}|>, 
 "Nepal" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 7., "EVI" -> 8.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 9., "EVI" -> 5.|>}|>, 
 "S. Islands" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 3., "EVI" -> 4.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 9., "EVI" -> 7.|>}|>, 
 "Kiribati" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 4., "EVI" -> 8.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 5., "EVI" -> 1.|>}|>, 
 "Vanuatu" -> <|2011. -> {<|"GDP" -> 6., "EVI" -> 3.|>}, 
   2015. -> {<|"GDP" -> 6., "EVI" -> 3.|>}|>|>
```

Now I like to Export `yeniDS` to a single worksheet in Excel in the following format:

- the first column in the worksheet should have country names;
- second, GDP for 2011;
- third, GDP for 2015;
- fourth, EVI for 2011;
- fifth, EVI for 2015.

I tried different versions of:

```
denemeSGIs = Join @@@ yeniDS;
Export["deneme.csv", denemeSGIs]
```

It does not work, I get `deneme.csv` in Excel, though.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an intermediate table, which could be your `denemeSGIs`, but I'll call it `denemeTable`, with the data columns in the desired order

```
denemeTable = Table[Flatten@{key,
     First[yeniDS[key][#]]["GDP"] & /@ {2011., 2015.}, 
     First[yeniDS[key][#]]["EVI"] & /@ {2011., 2015.}},
   {key, Sort@*Keys  @yeniDS}];

denemeTable // TableForm  (* // TeXForm *)
```

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{Angola} & 3. & 7. & 10.
   & 5. \\
 \text{Bangladesh} & 2. & 6. &
   7. & 9. \\
 \text{Bhutan} & 5. & 7. & 11.
   & 7. \\
 \text{Cambodia} & 6. & 3. &
   5. & 6. \\
 \text{Kiribati} & 4. & 5. &
   8. & 1. \\
 \text{Nepal} & 7. & 9. & 8. &
   5. \\
 \text{S. Islands} & 3. & 9. &
   4. & 7. \\
 \text{Vanuatu} & 6. & 6. & 3.
   & 3. \\
\end{array}$

Then export to both the Excel format and to the CSV format to see which one you like better when you open the files in Excel

```
Export["deneme.xls", denemeTable]
Export["deneme.csv", denemeTable]
```

#### Edit 1:

For lists of indicator and time keys, `denemeTable` can be generated like this:

```
indicatorList = {"GDP", "EVI"};
yearList = {2011., 2015.};

denemeTable = Table[Flatten@{key,
     Through /@ (Flatten[yeniDS[key] /@ yearList] /@ indicatorList)},
   {key, Sort@*Keys  @yeniDS}];
```

#### Edit 2: Column Names

One way to get the column headings from `indicatorList` and `yearList` is

```
columnNames = Flatten[{"Country",
   Outer[StringJoin @@ {#1, " for ", ToString[IntegerPart[#2]]} &, 
    indicatorList, yearList]}];

Export["deneme.xls", Join[{columnNames}, denemeTable]]
Export["deneme.csv", Join[{columnNames}, denemeTable]]
```

#### Edit 3: Using StringTemplate

If the exact form of the column headings might change, a `StringTemplate` could be used.  For example, we can define the following

```
template = StringTemplate["`ind` for `yr`"];
```

And we can apply the template like this:

```
columnNames = Flatten[{"Country",
   template /@ Flatten[Outer[<|"ind" -> #1, "yr" -> #2|> &,
      indicatorList, IntegerPart /@ yearList]]}];

Export["deneme.xls", Join[{columnNames}, denemeTable]]
Export["deneme.csv", Join[{columnNames}, denemeTable]]
```

The advantage here is that minor changes to the column names can be made by modifying the template without reading and trying to change the complicated code that is used to apply the template.

Comment: I have a long list of variables, and therefore it would be more efficient if I can create your `Table` by an automatic extraction of the variables. I can do the extraction. Call it `indicatorList` (i.e., key) as a list of variable names and map it onto your `Table` in place of `GDP`, `EVI` so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your code. Regards.

Comment: I noticed that the `indicatorList` is not shown in Excel worksheet. The first row in Excel worksheet should include the `indicatorList` with the years attached. I have a very large list of variables over many years. Please see the dataset created in the first `Answer`, which is the right format for me. Would be it be easy and possible to fix your code?

Answer (score 2):

```
ds = Dataset[yeniDS];
t1 = Normal@Keys[ds];
t2 = Normal@Values[ds][All, 1, 1, 1];
t3 = Normal@Values[ds][All, 2, 1, 1];
t4 = Normal@Values[ds][All, 1, 1, 2];
t5 = Normal@Values[ds][All, 2, 1, 2];

dataExcel = {{"Country", "GDP 2011", "GDP 2015", "EVI 2011", 
    "EVI 2015"}} ~Join~Transpose@Join[{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5}]
```

One can also use `Sort@Transpose...` for ordering this table. Adding the title row is optional.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{Country} & \text{GDP 2011} & \text{GDP 2015} & \text{EVI 2011} & \text{EVI 2015} \\
 \text{Bhutan} & 5. & 7. & 11. & 7. \\
 \text{Angola} & 3. & 7. & 10. & 5. \\
 \text{Bangladesh} & 2. & 6. & 7. & 9. \\
 \text{Cambodia} & 6. & 3. & 5. & 6. \\
 \text{Nepal} & 7. & 9. & 8. & 5. \\
 \text{S. Islands} & 3. & 9. & 4. & 7. \\
 \text{Kiribati} & 4. & 5. & 8. & 1. \\
 \text{Vanuatu} & 6. & 6. & 3. & 3. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

Alternately, and more concisely, the same result can be had with:

```
t6 = {{"Country", "GDP 2011", "GDP 2015", "EVI 2011", "EVI 2015"}} ~
  Join~Transpose@({Normal@Keys@ds}~
     Join~(Normal@Values[ds][All, Splice[#]] & /@ {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 
         1}, {1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}
      )
    )
```

---

Example:

```
Export["C:\\deneme.csv", dataExcel]
```